# Handling authentication when embedding salesforce visual page in external website

Tags: visualforce, authentication, oauth

I'm trying to embed salesforce visualforce page in an external website using the iframe. I've handled the issues with iframe but one thing I couldn't able to solve is how we can handle the authentication of the visualforce page in the external website. The external website is hosted in community. The external website is built with angular and uses auth token (created from salesforce) to invoke salesforce REST APIs. Is it possible to use this auth token to authenticate the visual force page? What are the other options we've? How we can avoid exposing another login page for visual force in the external site?

Comment: Look into [Embedded Login](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.externalidentityImplGuide.meta/externalidentityImplGuide/external_identity_login_intro.htm)

Answer (score 1):

VJAI,

You made a statement about the Visualforce page being hosted in a Community.  If this statement is true, I recommend recreating the visualforce page as a lightning component. Since the user is already authenticated by the community, if your were to use a lightning component, the need to re-authentic will no longer be needed.

Comment: Thanks first of all for answering this. Will try and if it works I'll accept this as answer.

Comment: When you say recreating you mean to build from scratch? or just embed that in a lightning component?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I'm suggesting that you MIGRATE the visualforce page to a lightning component. In short, you WILL be creating a new component, however, the existing logic/functionality of the Visualforce page will be revised and/or restructured, if needed, to play well in the newly created lightning component.